# Format string to datetime in Pandas without zero padding, AM/PM and UTC

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

My csv file contains the date and time values like below. I want to convert this to a datetime format in pandas but I keep getting errors.
I then want to convert it to a 24 hour format with zero padding and without the mention UTC.

I already tried : `format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p"`

```
10/12/2021 10:25 AM UTC   
9/28/2021 8:51 AM UTC   
7/27/2021 9:45 AM UTC   
2/2/2022 7:10 PM UTC
```

Desired output:

```
10/12/2021 10:25   
09/28/2021 08:51   
07/27/2021 09:45   
02/02/2022 19:10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`%m/%d/%Y %H:%M`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=False).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
```

output:

```
0    10/12/2021 10:25
1    09/28/2021 08:51
2    07/27/2021 09:45
3    02/02/2022 19:10
Name: date, dtype: object
```

used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['10/12/2021 10:25 AM UTC',
                            '9/28/2021 8:51 AM UTC',
                            '7/27/2021 9:45 AM UTC',
                            '2/2/2022 7:10 PM UTC']})
```